# Can't call class method within another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class

I have two classes found within my lib folder. Both files are found in the `lib/services` folder. I'm loading the files via this method in my initializer.

```
['account_helpers', 'facades', 'decorators', 'presenters', 'serializers', 'services', 'views', 'queries'].each do |folder|
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/#{folder}/*.rb"].each {|file| load file}
end
```

My two classes appear as so...

```
class MarketingEmail
  def self.send
    User.where('created_at >= ?', 15.days.ago).each do |user|
      MarketingEmailDecider(user).deliver
    end
  end
end

class MarketingEmailDecider < MarketingEmail
  def init(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def deliver
    puts "delivered"
  end
end
```

Whenever I run the code I get the following error

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `MarketingEmailDecider' for MarketingEmail:Class
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this? I'm having no other issues with running other classes in any of my other classes (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are not calling a constant `MarketingEmailDecider`, but youa re trying to execute a method: `MarketingEmailDecider(user)`. I believe you wanted: `MarketingEmailDecider.new(user).deliver`.

BTW, it is `initialize` in ruby, not `init`.

Comment: D'oh. Two major mistakes. Been working with other languages lately and ruby still feels a little rusty.

Comment: Yeah, know the feeling. it is really good to get back to ruby after a whole day with Angular. :)

Comment: I'll mark your answer correct by tomorrow. Have to go now. Thanks again!